# There is a value less than Global minimum!

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

[image: Question]

Here we see that minimum of the function $x+y+1/xy$ is obtained at $(1,1)$ which is $3$

However , $f(1,-1) = -1$. Then how is $f(1,1)$ actually the minimum?

Comment: By definition, there is no value less than the global minimum.

Answer (score 5):

It's not! The key is *local* minimum, meaning that $f(1, 1)$ is less than $f(x, y)$ for all $(x, y)$ near $(1, 1)$. More precisely, there is some $r > 0$ such that
$$\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2} < r \implies f(x, y) \ge f(1, 1).$$
But, $f(x, y) \ge f(1, 1)$ doesn't hold globally, i.e. $f$ does not have a global minimum at $(1, 1)$.

While local minimums can usually be determined purely with derivatives (which themselves are purely about the local behaviour of functions), global minimums are more tricky. You usually have to consider the behaviour of $f$ as $(x, y)$ gets very large (Can it go to $-\infty$? If not, how small can it get?), as well as compare the function value at each critical point (or at least, the critical points which might be local minimums).

In this case, if we take $(x, y) = (-t, -t)$ as $t \to \infty$, note that
$$f(x, y) = -2t + \frac{1}{t^2} \to -\infty.$$
That is, $f$ can become arbitrarily large and negative, and hence there will be no global minimum.

Comment: I see, one more thing , how can I check if an image exists in the curve for an arbitrary point (x,y) . This case (1,-1) , my friends argued that there is no image for (1,-1)

Comment: If a point is in the domain of the function, then it has an image. Since you didn't specify a domain, I assumed it was the natural domain, i.e. the set of points for which the given operations produce a sensible value (in this case, all $(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2$ except where $x = 0$ or $y = 0$). The point $(1, -1)$ is certainly in this natural domain, as it gives the sensible value $-1$, but if the original question restricts $f$'s domain to something like $(0, \infty) \times (0, \infty)$, then $(-1, 1)$ will have no image.

Comment: What exactly is the original question? Does it restrict the domain of $f$?

Comment: @SnehalSha: If the map $f$ is differentiable on all of its domain, then the global minima (if it exists at a finite point $(x,y)$) must be at one of the critical points which are local minima since it would be a local minima as well. If that's not the case, then you need to check the behavior of the map as $\lVert (x,y)\rVert\to\infty$ and the points where the map isn't differentiable in addition to the points where local minima occurs. In conclusion, to check for global minima, you need to inspect critical points, asymptotic behavior and points where the map is defined but not differentiable

Comment: Also, I suggest reading the definitions involved. Refer to the wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima#Definition) and recall that $\Bbb R^2$ is a metric space equipped with the Euclidean metric, so it makes sense to talk about local extremums by phrasing it as that the map attains an extrema at that point in some open ball around that point. This notion can be extended to general topological spaces as well by talking about nbds about a point.